# How to get rid of lists inside a list?

Tags: python, list

`[['2.0'], ['1.5'], ['1.4'], ['2.1'], ['2.2'], ['2.4'], ['3.0'], ['1.1'], ['1.0'], ['1.6']]`

and I need it to be `['2.0','1.5', etc]`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use *list comprehension* with *sequence assignment*:

```
final_list = [x for x, in original_list]
```

Mind the comma (`,`) in the list comprehension, which is essential.

Here we make the assumption that there is **only one element in each sublist**. Python will check this and error if it is not the case. This can be *desired* behavior (or perhaps you want to concatenate the elements).

Example:

```
>>> original_list = [['2.0'], ['1.5'], ['1.4'], ['2.1'], ['2.2'], ['2.4'], ['3.0'], ['1.1'], ['1.0'], ['1.6']]
>>> final_list = [x for x, in original_list]
>>> final_list
['2.0', '1.5', '1.4', '2.1', '2.2', '2.4', '3.0', '1.1', '1.0', '1.6']
```

Comment: Still can't get it fixed :(

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to go back to the point where the program reads a line from a file and needs to split the elements into different lists?

Comment: Example of a line: strawberry 2.0

Comment: @MariaLuht: I suggest you edit your question with all relevant information, the code thus far and a clearer problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
item_list = [['2.0'], ['1.5'], ['1.4'], ['2.1'], ['2.2'], ['2.4'], ['3.0'], ['1.1'], ['1.0'], ['1.6']]

print([item for sub_list in item_list for item in sub_list])
```

This will result in :

```
['2.0', '1.5', '1.4', '2.1', '2.2', '2.4', '3.0', '1.1', '1.0', '1.6']
```

Comment: Can you write it black and white? I'm really really really dumb at programming :D

Comment: black and white ?